# How can I make a label multiline?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `Label` that has a large amount of text. The value comes from a database. What I want is to view that text in a multiline `Label` but if the text is more than the width of the `Label` it cuts down.

Like:

```
----------------------------------
|This is a label and I want it to|
----------------------------------
```

But I want this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|This is a label and I want it to be multiline|
|when needed.                                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 36):

Follow these steps,

Go to properties of the label and set `AutoSize : false`

Now expend your label to max size of the content like.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now your text will not be go outside of the label and automatically go to next line when reach the end of the label.

Comment: but what if i don't want to make the label as large as the text. if the text is less then there will be more space remaining.?

Comment: you have to create. if you not then where will your large text take place?

Answer (score 16):

Go to Label *Properties* >> `AutoSize` = `True`, `False`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can display the required message in multiline on a lable.

To accomplish this you have to assign the required data into a variable in multiline.

Use the following codes to accomplish this:

`variable += variable  + vbCrLf`

This will help you assign the variable in multiline

```
label1.text = variable '
```

This will help to serve your purpose

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ComboBox with BackColor same as Parent, Border None and Multiline True